# Python Selenium Webdriver is not working in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, remote-debugging, headless-browser

Unable to create Python Chrome WebDriver in headless mode.

I am using Chrome version 108.0.5359.94.

I am also using the `Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())` to automatically install the compatible chromewebdriver.

**NOTE**: The same result happens if I download the applicable chrome webdriver and instead of using the service I use the executable_path.

The code for recreating this is very simple.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
print(driver)
```

When running in regular (not headless) mode I am getting the expected print of the webdriver object:

```
python selenium_test.py 
<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="9b6ec32017d8d864f8e2061293faee40")>
```

But when running in headless mode (same code simply remove the marker from the headless option line), I am getting the following error:

```
python selenium_test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boazz/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/selenium_test.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/boazz/.virtualenvs/reigo_qa_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/home/boazz/.virtualenvs/reigo_qa_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/boazz/.virtualenvs/reigo_qa_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 270, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/boazz/.virtualenvs/reigo_qa_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 363, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/boazz/.virtualenvs/reigo_qa_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 428, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/boazz/.virtualenvs/reigo_qa_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5588159a82a3 <unknown>
#1 0x558815766f77 <unknown>
#2 0x55881578f5f7 <unknown>
#3 0x55881578b7d0 <unknown>
#4 0x5588157cc0b7 <unknown>
#5 0x5588157cba5f <unknown>
#6 0x5588157c3903 <unknown>
#7 0x558815796ece <unknown>
#8 0x558815797fde <unknown>
#9 0x5588159f863e <unknown>
#10 0x5588159fbb79 <unknown>
#11 0x5588159de89e <unknown>
#12 0x5588159fca83 <unknown>
#13 0x5588159d1505 <unknown>
#14 0x558815a1dca8 <unknown>
#15 0x558815a1de36 <unknown>
#16 0x558815a39333 <unknown>
#17 0x7fa6443c0b43 <unknown>
```

I expected the chrome driver to be created regardless if I am using the headless option or not. What could be the cause for that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with a port you trying to set for debugging.
I tried your code and it did not work for me too, but when I changed the port from `9222` to `61625` it worked.
So, at least for me this worked:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=61625')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
print(driver)
```

The output is

```
<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="70ca99a865d0eb7b93a95f530ef1401b")>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, unfortunately changing the port on my setup does not work. I am running it on Linux.

Comment: Try another port.

Comment: do you know why my case is not working ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093600/option-add-argument-headless-new-doesnt-work-for-chrome-122-when-scrap-kay

Comment: @ErikJohnsson These days I'm not active here, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different approach?
Like using WebDriverManager to create your driver, see link below:
https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager